# Netbeans 8.2 does not create a single project

Tags: java, console, netbeans-8

I have downloaded NetBeans 8.2 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, but when I click "new project" or "new file" nothing happens. It does not send me any error message or something like that. I can wait all day for the file/project to open and it will not open.

You may be wondering if I have java jdk already installed on my computer. Yes, I have it. When I put the command:`java --version`
the console shows me:

`openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)`

EDITED: here is the logs i got from:`[Netbeans Location]/nb/var/log/messages.log`

i posted to download because the message is too long to COPY and PASTE here, so, here is the link:

https://www.4shared.com/file/a6_Ml0Pada/messages.html

Comment: navigate to: `[Netbeans Location]/nb/var/log/messages.log`
paste us the logs so we can see what's going on.

Comment: done Alan Deep, i posted the messages.log on 4shared cause was to long to copy and paste here